# How can you add to a variable based on the occurrence of a data criteria, which may occur in 1 or more rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table [EVENT_DATA] that reads data from a PLC. There are n tags that read ('TempZone1','TempZone2','TempZone3',etc...) every 5 seconds the table is updated with the temps for each zone, so I have something that looks like...

| DateTime | TagName | DataValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-01 07:00:05 | TempZone1 | 371 |
| 2024-02-01 07:00:05 | TempZone2 | 379 |
| 2024-02-01 07:00:05 | TempZone3 | **368** |
| 2024-02-01 07:00:10 | TempZone1 | **369** |
| 2024-02-01 07:00:10 | TempZone2 | 380 |
| 2024-02-01 07:00:10 | TempZone3 | **367** |

I am adding up the total minutes that **any**  of the TempZones is < 370, so for the first group of 3 at 07:00:05 there is 5 seconds(only 1 row <370), and in the second set at 07:00:10 there is also only 5 seconds(even though there are 2 rows <370), since any one of the values is under 370 I want to ignore any of the other 'n' rows tied to the same DateTime.

I have code that currently gives me 15 seconds of time grouped by TempZone3 = 10 seconds and TempZone1 = 5 seconds, all I want is a separate variable(TotalColdMin) that has only the 10 seconds total.

```
TotalColdMin=
(1+datediff(mi,z.lo_date,z.hi_date))*(issues/convert(real,evt))
```

In the above code, lo_date = 'mm/dd/yyy 07:00:00' and hi_date = 'mm/dd/yyyy 07:59:59'

'issues' is calculated by
`issues= sum(case when datavalue < 370.0 then 1 else 0 end)`

Unfortunately, this gives me the total minutes for each of the zones, I do not care which zone is below, nor do I care if more than 1 zone is below 370 at the same time. I want to record only that one of them was below, regardless of which one it was.

I'm hoping that I have explained what I need clearly enough to see what it is I am after.

Comment: Do you want to get original data together with the totalcoldmin-thingy, or do you want to get some kind of aggregated value per DateTime?

Comment: Sample data **and** desired results would clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about multiple zones in the same DateTime group being under 370, then the easiest way would probably be to group by DateTime, and then grab the minimum value for each group. You would then filter by DataValue < 370 and multiply by 5 seconds. The initial group by would like something like this:

```
SELECT DateTime, MIN(DataValue)
FROM [EVENT_DATA]
GROUP BY DateTime
```

My SQL is a little rusty so I won't attempt the second statement, but you simply count where DataValue < 370 and multiply by 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but I actually figured out what works best for my needs. I exposed the individual tags and assigned them to variables then rejoined the table to itself with joins on the time and the zones, then used the CASE to capture only 1 of the 3 zones. It took over 1 minute to run until I threw in an index on the table on the time field, now it runs in less than 1 second.

```
sum(case WHEN isnull(d1.DATAVALUE,0) < 370 then 1 WHEN isnull(d2.DATAVALUE,0) < 370 then 1 WHEN isnull(d3.DATAVALUE,0) < 370 THEN 1 else 0 end)
```

The above gives me my number of distinct events that occurs at each 5 second interval, then I just do the math on that number to get my minutes per hour.

The joins ended up looking like the below...

```
join [EVENT_DATA] d1 on D1.TAG_KEY = @ZONE1
LEFT JOIN [EVENT_DATA] d2 ON d2.UTC_TIME = d1.UTC_TIME AND d2.TAG_KEY = @ZONE2
LEFT JOIN [EVENT_DATA] d3 ON d3.UTC_TIME = d1.UTC_TIME d3.TAG_KEY = @ZONE3
```